# How to change language display name in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay

I would like to change language display name in Liferay 6.2. For example i would love to change Српски (Serbia) [Beta] to Srpski ? Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that these translations are taken from the Java Runtime (with the beta being declared in Liferay's [portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Languages%20and%20Time%20Zones))

However, there are two serbian versions (one with kyrillic and one with latin characters) and it might be enough to just use the other - please test it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it is possible, because language name display is based on `java.util.Locale` (http://www.localeplanet.com/java/).